# Hi can anyone decipher this stamp please?

Tags: translation

[image]It's from a Chinese scroll I was given by a collector about 10 years ago. The person who gave it to me died recently.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the right three letter is “陳从周” 

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 characters in this stamp  陈从周手稿

陈从周 is a famous architect and artist. Here comes the link for 陈从周 https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%99%88%E4%BB%8E%E5%91%A8/4459?fr=aladdin, you can get more information from this page.